# Copy Every So Many Rows to New Sheet Column A, B, etc

Tags: excel, vba

Would it be possible in Excel VBA to copy every 950 rows to columns in a new sheet?

Ex: If there were over 4000 rows in column A Sheet1 to then move every 950 rows to Sheet2 Column A, Next 950 rows to Sheet2 Column B, etc.

I tried Transpose but instead of putting it into columns vertically, it still does the rows horizontal so instead of moving to column A Sheet2 rows 1-950, it was doing A1 - H1 (I've been testing on small datasets).

Is there a method better than transpose?

Comment: If you want an answer from the community you'll need to include a much more detailed description of what you've tried so far. Consider including: The formulas you tried, any code you tried, images of current-v-expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Single Column To Columns

[image]

**Utilization**

```vb
Sub ColToColsTEST()

    Const ROWS_PER_COLUMN As Long = 6

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A2")
    
    ColToCols srg, dfCell, ROWS_PER_COLUMN
    
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub ColToCols( _
        ByVal SourceSingleColumnRange As Range, _
        ByVal DestinationFirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal RowsPerColumn As Long)
    
    ' Write the values from the Source range to the Source array.
    
    Dim sData() As Variant, srCount As Long
    
    With SourceSingleColumnRange.Columns(1)
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        If srCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Define the Destination array.
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = Int(srCount / RowsPerColumn)
    Dim ldrCount As Long: ldrCount = srCount Mod RowsPerColumn
    
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    If dcCount = 0 Then drCount = ldrCount Else drCount = RowsPerColumn
    If ldrCount > 0 Then dcCount = dcCount + 1
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Write from the Source To the Destination array: all but the last column.
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, dc As Long
    
    For dc = 1 To dcCount - 1
        For dr = 1 To drCount
            sr = sr + 1
            dData(dr, dc) = sData(sr, 1)
        Next dr
    Next dc
    
    ' Write from the Source To the Destination array: the last column.
    
    If ldrCount = 0 Then ldrCount = drCount
    
    For dr = 1 To ldrCount
        sr = sr + 1
        dData(dr, dc) = sData(sr, 1)
    Next dr
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination array to the Destination range.
    
    With DestinationFirstCell
        .Resize(drCount, dcCount).Value = dData
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to do.